Roblox default animate script not working on NPC
So I'm trying to use the default Roblox "Animate" client side script on an NPC and when I try it, none of the animations load at all
When I try to run the game with the code, nothing happens and there is no errors on the output. If you can, I would appreciate help on this

LocalScripts run only in certain locations:
https://create.roblox.com/docs/projects/data-model#client
You can replace the Animate LocalScript with a ServerScript or a ServerScript with RunContext set to Client.

Thank you so much, this worked. I just put the script in StarterGui
